# Examples of widgets that use Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am evaluating Elasticsearch as a datasource for my dashboard analytics.
Does anybody have or know for an example of client side library (JQuery, Dojo ...) that takes result of ES JSON faceted search and renders some nice charts.

I 've seen protovis example on elasticsearch blog, but not very keen to make proof of concept with protovis, since it is officially discontinued project.

Thanks in advance,
Clandestino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at Highcharts ([www.highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/)).
If you want to see some example, take a look at [BigDesk](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk) which is a live statistics monitor for elasticsearch.

Note: be sure to check highcharts license to see if it matches your use case.